# Arguments are stored as pair and not as number?

Tags: scheme, lisp

In University we’re building a Scheme Interpreter in Scheme. In the code below you can see the implementation for the plus operator.

```
#lang racket

(define (EVAL e)
    (if (pair? e) ;if its a pair its a function -> call EVALFunctionCall
        (EVALFunctionCall e)
        (null))) ;null - other cases are not implemented

(define (EVALFunctionCall e)
    (if (eq? (car e) '+) ;if its + its addition -> call EVALPlus
        (EVALPlus (cdr e))
        (null))) ;null - other cases are not implemented

(define (EVALPlus argList) 
    ;for debugging
    (display (car argList))(display "\n")
    (display (cdr argList))(display "\n")
    (display (car (cdr argList)))(display "\n")
    (display (cdr (cdr argList)))(display "\n")

    (+ (car argList) (cdr argList)))
```

`(EVAL '(+ 1 2))` should evaluate to `3`. But it does not. Instead I get an Error. 
This is because `(cdr argList)` (the second argument I pass to +-function) is not a number but a pair. The displays I added for debugging print out:

```
1
(2)
2
()
```

I am pretty sure this is the code the prof showed in the lesson (which worked). So what did I wrong? Is it possible that my prof uses another scheme-dialect which does `'(+ 1 2)` save like `(+(1 2))` and not like `(+(1(2 null)))` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a little bug in your code, try this in the `EVALPlus` procedure:

```
(+ (car argList) (car (cdr argList)))
```

Remember that `cdr` retrieves the next *list*, not the next *element*. After obtaining the next list, we call `car` to obtain its first element.

Comment: Thanks! Of course this is how my prof implemented it. Shame on me I didn't find my own mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the obvious solution would be:

```
(define (EVALPlus argList)
   (apply + argList))
```

However, since the exercise is about implementing a Scheme interpreter, that would probably be cheating ;-)

What about a simple cumulative sum then:

```
(define (EVALPlus argList)
   (cond ((null? argList) 0)
         ((null? (cdr argList)) (car argList))
         (#t (+ (car argList) (EVALPlus (cdr argList))))))
```

Or, if you're not allowed `cond`:

```
(define (EVALPlus argList)
   (if (null? argList) 0
      (if (null? (cdr argList)) (car argList)
         (+ (car argList) (EVALPlus (cdr argList))))))
```

As always, beware of the special cases:

```
(EVAL '(+)) ; no argument
=> 0
(EVAL '(+ 42)) ; only one argument
=> 42
(EVAL '(+ 1 3 5 7 9)) ; n arguments
=> 25
```

Hope it helps.